# All reopen voted questions on profile are marked as deleted

Tags: bug, profile-page, reopened-questions

I just noticed all questions I have voted to reopen on are marked as deleted on my profile (`https://stackoverflow.com/users/508666/peehaa?tab=votes&sort=reopen`):

[image]

But they really aren't deleted.

Example question: [Learning .prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660090/learning-prototype)